# Determine Type of Kendo UI Control

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following utility function that works (obviously it only looks for 5 types of controls, but that's all I use):

```
util.getKendoControlType = function(controlId) {
    let controlTypes = ['kendoAutoComplete','kendoMultiSelect','kendoDatePicker','kendoDropDownList','kendoNumericTextBox'];
    for(let i = 0; i < controlTypes.length; i++) {
        let control = $('#' + controlId).data(controlTypes[i]);
        if (typeof(control) !== 'undefined' && control !== null) {
            return controlTypes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

My question: is this the only way to get the control type of a Kendo UI control, or is there a better way?

(Note: I'm aware that instead of returning null, I could also throw an error.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! Use [`kendo.widgetInstance`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/widgetinstance):

```
util.getKendoControlType = function(controlId) {
    return kendo.widgetInstance($(`#${controlId}`)).options.name;
}
```

You can also get the *role* data attribute:

```
util.getKendoControlType = function(controlId) {
    return $(`#${controlId}`).data('role');
}
```

Comment: Much nicer way to grab the control, and upvoted accordingly. But this grabs the control itself. Is there a way to get the type?

Comment: @Jason I see, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you for this.  I was not aware of 'role'